# Compression Enabled, smaller IS expected, BUT 3,000 files, Size=25GB but Size on Disk only 5MB?

Tags: compression, properties, size, windirstat

I've looked & keep finding lots of articles telling me what I already know.

I know the file size difference is because I have `Compress contents to save disk space` enabled.

I know about the difference between block size & clusters & all that.

I know about sparse files & small files in the Index/MFT.

But the difference is too great for any of that to be explained by those.

Now the folder is mostly filled with text, epub, mobi, pdf, docx, etc. But has many that have images in them & even some 100MB+ jpg & png CBZ files.

The `Size:` was stated to be `24.6GB`, which seems to be as expected.
When I saw the `Size on disk:` I thought it was a bit much for the compression since it said `459MB` so I was a bit concerned, but then I noticed I had overlooked the decimal & it was actually only **`4.59MB`** which is completely impossible. Even if it was ***ONLY*** text I'm pretty sure 24GB of text being compressed to only 5MB is smaller than, or at least close to if not, what is possible with current technology.

The idea of sparse files also doesn't seem plausible for such a huge size reduction.
It's **0.000018 the size of the original** that's like essentially 18% ***of*** 1% ***of*** 1% of the original.  Like you took 1 part out of 100, broke that into 100 pieces, then took 1 of those, then broke it into 100 pieces then took 18 of those. Just the metadata for a sparse file for that many zero blocks would take up too much space for that to add up.

With the current, as I am now writing it, test 3, `Size on Disk`: is `377MB` about `1.5%` of the `24.9GB` current total `size:`, which is a lot higher, but still unreasonably smaller than any solution seems to make sense.

WinDirStat & TreeSize-Free show the same problem.
When testing TreeSize-Free  in my 2nd test the file size had changed as things got added to the folder during normal use, as it was a couple days later, but the new sizes are consistent with Windows' `Properties`

**Windows** (Test 2)

- Size on Disk: 319MB &
- Size: 24.9 GB

**WinDirStat**  (Test 2)

- Size: 319.1MB

**TreeSize-Free**  (Test 2)

- Size: 25GB
- Allocated: 319.2MB

The files in the folder seem to be fine, I don't see any problems with the content. I checked & the folder is not a part of any junction, symbolic link, or Hardlink.

I don't want to loose anything by causing a problem but don't know how I should handle or fix this problem...

The system is:

- Windows 10 Pro (21H2)
- OS Build: 19044.2130

---

[Image of Properties for Folder #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O7cE.jpg)

[Image of Properties for Folder #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITgfx.jpg)

---

Similar Questions, all others seem to be essentially saying the same things as there 3:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644974/how-can-a-folder-size-be-larger-than-its-size-on-disk

[How can the size on disk be smaller than size?](https://superuser.com/questions/518414/how-can-the-size-on-disk-be-smaller-than-size)

[Reverse diff in size between file 'size' and 'size on disk'](https://superuser.com/questions/1442840/reverse-diff-in-size-between-file-size-and-size-on-disk)

Comment: Odd indeed.. I have only one thought.. those are magic files.  DON'T DELETE THEM.  You can sprinkle them across the MFT and end up with a larger disk!

Comment: Yeah, that's really not helpful. I know the files aren't magically taking up no space. But if the system & 3rd party tools are showing them with such a discrepancy I'm afraid at some point there may be a problem & I'd rather find out why they are like that before that happens. I have made a backup, But it seems like the files newly added are sizing fine, so after enough time they may get into the same problem. If, say it's taking up sectors on my less than half filled 1TB drive but those sectors aren't being marked as used... a defrag or file written could overwrite something